# Setting a default layout for all Markdown files

Tags: astrojs

I'd like to fetch Markdown files from another repository when building an astro site, but these Markdown files do not have the `layout` frontmatter property.

Is there a way to 'force' markdown files to use a default layout without touching their frontmatter headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible with [Content Collections](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/).

Have your Markdown files wrapped in a collection, and have the corresponding  `[...slug].astro` file use the default layout.

```
---
import { getCollection } from "astro:content";
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/DefaultLayout.astro";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const entries = await getCollection("markdown");
  return entries.map((entry) => ({
    params: { slug: entry.slug },
    props: { entry },
  }));
}

const { entry } = Astro.props;
const { Content } = await entry.render();
---

<DefaultLayout frontmatter={entry.data}>
  <Content />
</DefaultLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

There has been a plugin recently created to do this:

https://github.com/EccentricVamp/astro-default-layout

Plugin is based on these comments if you prefer to roll your own:

https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/397#issuecomment-1264718819